# Recyclerview inside Jetpack Compose Column is not getting onScrolled events

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose

I have this Column that wraps the entire screen. There is also an AndroidView(RecyclerView) as it's child.

The issue is that when I make the Column scrollable, then the recyclerview adapter is not getting any onScrolled events. My goal is to have the entire screen scrollable, and at the same time get scroll events in my recyclerview adapter

```
  **Column(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxSize()
      .verticalScroll(scrollState),**
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
  ) {
    SomeComposables()
    Column(
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
      TopText()
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
      **AndroidViewList() -> This is an AndroidView that has a RecyclerViewInside**
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can I ask why aren't you using `LazyColumn`

Comment: unfortunately it isn't possible at the moment